# Get Unique IP Address and # of Access

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, logging

I found the following code to see which IP Addresses has the highest hits:

> FILE=access.log; for ip in `cat $FILE |cut -d ' ' -f 1 |sort |uniq`; do { COUNT=`grep ^$ip $FILE |wc -l`; if [[ "$COUNT" -gt "500" ]]; then echo "$COUNT:   $ip"; fi }; done

The above code displays the IP address with more than 500 hits (i.e. access on the site by opening the URL)

But that script is too slow. Is there any other code that create the same output?

Plus, how to display the top 10 results only that has the highest hits or access on the URL?

Comment: how big is the access.log file?

Comment: Average 125MB/day..

Comment: Try log aggregation with Logstash and Kibana.

Comment: Short answer: yes.  `cut -d' ' -f1 access.log | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 ~ /[5-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+/'`.  Only reads through your access log once rather than once per IP address.  You can add `| sort -n` on the end if you want them sorted by hits.

Answer (score 1):

You're re-inventing the wheel. Try this:

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\).*$/\1/' -e t -e d access.log | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Thanks. How to get top 10 or top 20 only with highest hits?

Comment: Just add '| head -n 20' to the end of the command above.